# fixed Column width in files

Tags: pantheon-files

one thing bothers me a bit. I'd like to have the option to fix the column width in pantheon files-column view. They're all messed up when there's one file with a really long file name (e.g. Music files).

Is there a solution for this out there and is somebody having the same issue as me?

cheers

[image: column_width]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you raise an issue at https://github.com/elementary/files/issues.  It would not be too hard to implement - except that it would involve another setting which may not meet the approval of the UX team.

At the moment, the extent to which the columns can expand is limited to 3 times the "preferred_column_width" - the latter defaults to 180 pixels.

If you set the preferred column width to a smaller number - say 60 (you need to edit the setting "io.elementary.files.column-view.preferred-column-width" using dconf-editor or the commandline 'gsettings set io.elementary.files.column-view preferred-column-width nnn') - then most columns will be at or near their maximum width and a pseudo fixed width effect can be obtained.

Comment: Sweet! I'll check that out.